# Load Next Page in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following Angular and HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var application = angular.module('Application', []);

  application.service('ImageService', function ($http) {
    return {
      GetList: function () {
        return $http.get('api/images');
      },
    }
  });

  application.controller('ImageController', function ImageController($scope, ImageService) {

    ImageService.GetList()
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.images = data;
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
  });

</script>

<div data-ng-app="Application" data-ng-controller="ImageController" class="gallery">
  <div data-ng-repeat='image in images' class="image">
    <img src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The API call is returning the following:

```
[
  {"Key":"89207","Url":"http://somedomain.com/image89207.jpg"},
  {"Key":"12321","Url":"http://somedomain.com/image12321.jpg"},
  {"Key":"23434","Url":"http://somedomain.com/image23434.jpg"}
]
```

I would like to load the next page when the user scrolls down to the end of the page or when it clicks a button saying "Show More".

I also need to return on my JSON the NextPage value ...

The point is that if current page is "233" then next page might be "4545".

I think the API might need to return the next page value and a list of images.

How can I do this?

Comment: You're right -- the API should return the next page value.

Comment: But how can I load the next page when the user scrolls to the end of the page or when it clicks a button saying "show more"?

Comment: you need to make $http call on show more click. server should take page and pageSize option, so that it will process request and give proper response,

Comment: But wouldn't that hide the current images? I would like to add the new images to the ones that are already being displayed ...

Comment: create a $scope.dataVariable = []. and on click of "show more" get new data and push into the scope variable. ng-repeat will take care  of new data.it will render automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with pankajparkar. You should handle 'show more' button, load more images and join it with $scope.images. ng-repeat will do remaining work. Here is code sample

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var application = angular.module('Application', []);

    application.service('ImageService', function($http) {
      return {
        GetList: function(page) {
          return $http.get('api/images', {
            params: {
              page: page
            }
          });
        },
      }
    });

    application.controller('ImageController', function ImageController($scope, ImageService) {

      var page = 0;

      $scope.images = [];

      var load = function() {
        ImageService.GetList(page)
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.images = $scope.images.concat(data);
          })
          .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
      };

      load();

      $scope.loadMore = function() {
        page++;
        load();
      }
    });
  </script>

  <div data-ng-app="Application" data-ng-controller="ImageController" class="gallery">
    <div data-ng-repeat='image in images' class="image">
      <img src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <button ng-click="loadMore()">load more</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The problem with your code is that it does not load any images on start ... I tried to change it to: var page = 0; $scope.images = []; load(); ... But somehow this does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: And a side note: any reason why you use button for ng-click and not an anchor (a)?

Comment: Yes, you are right - I forget call load() on start. I've made correction. (May be you called 'load()' before 'var load = ...' ?).
No special reason for button - it can be any element.

Comment: Yes, that was the mistake I made. I called load before ... Thanks